# AVSPEED IConf.net SDK video confrencing

Tags: c#, wpf, video-conferencing, iconfsdk

I am using Iconf.net Sdk to do video conferencing. Right now audio conference calls works perfectly. But when i try to view users video its not showing up. Here is my code

**Initialization**

```
icc = new iConfClient.NET.iConfClientDotNet();
ics = new iConfServerDotNet();
pnlics.Child = ics;
ics.Show();
pnlicc.Child = icc;
icc.Show();
icc.SetImage(null);
```

**Button event from which call is genrated**

```
private void CentralServerCall_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                callType = "Video";
                ArrayList usersToInvite = new ArrayList();
                if (UserName.Text == "user2")
                    usersToInvite.Add("user1");
                else
                    usersToInvite.Add("user2");
                ics.SelectVideoDevice(1);
                ics.StartPreview(cbVideoPreviewSizes.SelectedIndex);
                ics.StartConference(usersToInvite);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }


        }
```

**Once the call is made between two users I click on view other user video to see his Video stream**

```
private void ViewUser_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (UserName.Text == "user2")
                ics.ViewUser("user1");
            else
                ics.ViewUser("user2");
        }
```

**Event to receive stream**

```
private void ics_ViewUserResponseReceived(object sender, System.String userName, System.Int32 port,
                                          System.Int32 videoWidth, System.Int32 videoHeight,
                                          System.String videoCodec)
{
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(delegate
    {
        icc.InitializeEngine(videoCodec, videoWidth, videoHeight);
        icc.Call("localhost", port, videoWidth, videoHeight, "n/a", "","", 0, 0, 0, videoCodec);
    }
    ));

}
```

Can anyone please guide me, and please also tell me how can I achieve this for more than one user. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't missed anything in the code. The issue is that the video call uses different ports to the audio and it's being blocked by a firewall. I haven't looked into exactly which ports, but when I tried allowing any connections between my devices it worked as expected.